# JAXB ignores @XmlAttribute annotation

Tags: java, xml, annotations, jaxb

It seems that JAXB ignores `@XmlAttribute` annotation and does not populate `attributeName` and `attributeValue` attributes.
Could you please help me to solve this problem?

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Product>
    <ProductCode>PRD191_5</ProductCode>
    <AttrList>
        <element Name="Toy Type" Value="Quadrocopter"/>
        <element Name="Engine Type" Value="Electric Engine"/>
        <element Name="Build Type" Value="Ready-To-Fly"/>
    </AttrList>
</Product>
```

Java classes:

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "Product")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Product {
    
    @XmlElement(name = "ProductCode")
    private String productCode;

    @XmlElement(name = "AttrList")
    private List<Attribute> attrList = null;
}
```

```
@XmlRootElement(name = "element")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Attribute {

    @XmlElement(name="element")
    @Column
    private String element;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Name", required=true)
    @Column
    private String attributeName;

    @XmlAttribute(name = "Value", required=true)
    @Column
    private String attributeValue;
}
```

Maven dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.xml.bind</groupId>
    <artifactId>jaxb-api</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some errors in your model definition: the `@XmlElement` of the `attrList` attribute should be set to `element` (the element that repeats itself), while the name of the wrapper element `<AttrList>` should be conveyed with the `@XmlElementWrapper` annotation:

```java
@XmlRootElement(name = "Product")
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class Product {
    
    @XmlElement(name = "ProductCode")
    private String productCode;
    
    @XmlElementWrapper(name = "AttrList")
    @XmlElement(name = "element")
    private List<Attribute> attrList = null;
}
```

You should also delete the Java Bean property `Attribute#element`, since it would denote a subelement named `<element>` of the `<element>` tag.